# Using Switches for Yes/No Checkboxes

Tags: toggle

I have a large form and many questions are simply Yes/No questions. In the system it's simple a checkbox, checked means yes, unchecked means no.

To make this visually more interesting than a standard checkbox I've used switches, specifically [ZURB Foundation (v6 for sites) Switches](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/switch.html).

Here is an example of what the states look like:

[image: switch example]

My concern is the user experience of the switches. While it's obvious for me, the first person I shared the development with said he didn't understand the switches. He got it once I explained it but this leads me to my question:

What would be the best way to help users understand this? I've considered adding color to the switch, red = unchecked and green = yes.

But I believe the main problem for the switches in this state is if the user, by flipping the switch, is selecting no or yes. They are unsure which they are selection.

Would color alone help solve the issue or what can I do to improve the user experience and help make this more clear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the toggle 'yes' when I see 'yes', or when the slider is slid to the left? Both make a certain amount of sense, but it's very ambiguous. Changing colors won't change that, and color should not be the main differentiation anyway.

If you're going for a slider you should use

```
no [  □] yes
```